# "Отрекать" и "отрицать"

Tags: этимология

Почему в русском языке не используются слова отрекать и отрекание (отреканье) вместо старославянизмов отрицать и отрицание?

Comment: А что такое "заместо"? А замес-то крут будет...

Comment: Ну одного (отрекание) вроде и не было, был глагол, а оставшиеся странно смешивать по смыслу: они особенные. Замес невозможен.

Comment: Слова «нарицание, нарекание» ещё дальше уводят от темы. Другие смыслы и... отсутствие проблемы.

Comment: http://feb-web.ru/feb/sl18/slov-abc/15/sli08005.htm?cmd=p&istext=1

Answer (score 2):

Вы заметили очень интересное и важное явление в русском (и не только русском, конечно) языке. Действительно, некоторые слова выходят из употребления полностью или частично. Основная причина этого явления в выборе слов носителями языка — именно они определяют в первую очередь, какое слово "выживет в эволюционной борьбе", а какое нет.

Что касается слова "отрекать", то оно всё ещё может употребляться в церковной речи, а форму "отрекаться" Вы и сами наверняка слышали и употребляли — это одно из распространённых слов русского языка (оно входит в частотный словарь 20 тыс. самых употребляемых слов).